# Automatically update field according to timestamp

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, sql-update

If I have the following table in mysql:

```
Table 1:

id   name   expired       exp_date   
1   Andrew     0      2015-12-09 20:00:00
2    John      1      2013-01-01 20:00:00
3    Mike      0      2017-01-13 21:00:00
```

what is the best way for mysql to automatically change the 'expired' field to '1' once the exp_date is passed?

Comment: While you _could_ do it using a [MySQL Scheduled Event](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html), I would personally suggest running a script from cron that fires the update statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have commented and answered with the suggestion to use MySQL events while I was writing my answer, but I'll include an example:

```
CREATE EVENT expire_table1
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR 
  DO UPDATE table1 SET expired = 1 WHERE expired = 0 AND exp_date < NOW();
```

It would be useful to have an index on `(expired, exp_date)` to make that UPDATE lock only the rows it needs to.

Be sure to enable the event scheduler. It's off by default, and that trips up a lot of people who want to use it:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

Read the documentation for more details here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use mysql Events, run it once a day to update the table comparing exp_date to the current date

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: There must be an echo in here.